# How to use GET with links/flask

Tags: python, html, flask, get

I've got a (flask) website I'm developing, and was wondering if there is a way to send GET from an `<a>` link, so when I click on the link the url changes from `localhost:5000/a_page` to `localhost:5000/a_page?imtype=egtype1`? I am using flask, so if there is an easier through that, then suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask has a way to do this. In the href parameter on the  element, simply put:

```
href="{{ url_for('a_page', imtype='egtype1') }}"
```